# python program - modify columns in text file

Tags: python, file, text

I need to delete a few columns in textfile, one of them is in the middle, and add two new.
This is my code. It works apart from the first line. How can I make it work for all lines?

```
infile = open('a.txt').read()
list =infile.split( );
print ("Hello " + list[0]+ "world" + list[2] + " " + list[3]+"313")
```

For example, I have got 5 columns in my original file:

```
1 2 3 4 5           
5 2 2 5 2           
1 2 5 6 2           
1 2 5 1 2           
1 5 6 7 8
```

The output is supposed to look like this:

```
1 "yyy" 4 "xxx"
5 "yyy" 5 "xxx"
1 "yyy" 6 "xxx"
1 "yyy" 1 "xxx"
1 "yyy" 7 "xxx"
```

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name. You are shadowing the builtin list which is never a good idea. You don't need `;` and always use `with` to open your files as it closes them automatically. `infile.readlines()` will put the content into a list, then just iterate over the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated answer** due to updated specifications:

Apply `split` to each line separately, then print your formatted line. If you just want to print the result:

```
with open('a.txt', 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        line = line.split()
        new_line = '{0} "yyy" {1} "xxx"'.format(line[0], line[3])
        print(new_line)
```

If you want to write the output to a new file `b.txt` (instead of just printing it):

```
with open('a.txt', 'r') as infile:
    with open('b.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        for line in infile:
            line = line.split()
            new_line = '{0} "yyy" {1} "xxx"\n'.format(line[0], line[3])
            outfile.write(new_line)
```

Output for your sample file:

```
1 "yyy" 4 "xxx"
5 "yyy" 5 "xxx"
1 "yyy" 6 "xxx"
1 "yyy" 1 "xxx"
1 "yyy" 7 "xxx"
```

Comment: @user3832446 didn't thought what?

Comment: But I still have proble to modify your code for my own file which have much more lines and columns.. I dont know why..

Comment: @user3832446 Of course you have to modify  the code if you want something different from what you asked for...

Comment: Ok - I found problem, there were a blank lines in file. Thanks!

Comment: Can U help me with one more thing? How can I delete all lines in file that don't start with "T"?

Comment: @user3832446 open the file and loop over the lines like in the code above, but only issue the write command `if not line.startswith('T')`.

Comment: Sorry for spamming but I have anouther question.. 
Since I've got worked code (thanks to you) I want to optimize it.
I want to modify text file:  a -> d
But right now I've got sth like: a -> b -> c -> d
How can I connect two or more loops?

Comment: @morks I think you should open a new question for that, it's hard to answer with code in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

split by default splits at whitespaces ... you can check the length of your list.

Try doing a readlines() and iterate over it doing what you have done.

Answer (score -2):

Using the method read() on your opened file object will read the entire content of your file as one string. Thus to even store each line as a list, you would have to split the string based on the row delimiter (\n, \r, \n\r). Using the readlines() method will store the contents of your file as a list object by line.

To answer your question about updating the contents of your file, I would use the readlines() method and list comprehension to do this quickly with few lines of code.  See the code example below. The variables row_delimiter and new_content may be replaced with whatever you need.

```
#declare paths
path1 = "C:\foo.txt"
path2 = "C:\bar.txt"

#read file and update content
with open(path1, "r") as read:
      content = [line.split(row_delimiter) for line in read.readlines()]
      [row[index] = new_content for row in content]
read.close()

#write new content 
with open(path2, "r") as wrt:
      [wrt.write(line) for line in content]
      wrt.close()
```

Comment: 1. The assignment in the list comprehension will throw a syntax error. 2. You don't need to close a file manually when opening it with `with`. 3. If you want to write to a file, you must open it with `'w'` or `'r+'`, not `'r'`. 4. Using a list comprehension solely for a side effect is a horrible practice.